# $_COOKIE is empty on the remote server

Tags: php, cookies

I am trying to set cookie so I do

```
setcookie("MyCookie", "Cookied Value", time()+3600,"/");
print_r($_COOKIE);
```

this works on my localhost and I get

```
Array (
    [PHPSESSID] => 3443c96e8b0d9a17e270ee83c023f2f2
    [MyCookie] => Cookied Value
)
```

but always empty array on the remote server. Is it server turning off cookie array?

Comment: Did you try setting the domain also?

Comment: yes, I did but no luck

Comment: `$_COOKIE` only stores whatever was sent in the request's `Cookie` header; it won't show cookies that were set in the same script. Is the variable empty even after you refresh the page?

Comment: Refresh your page after setting up cookie

Comment: surely I did refresh, as I said all is working on the localhost but not working on the remote server